# Changing DPI when exporting SVG to PDF with Inkscape (command line)

Tags: pdf, svg, command-line, export, inkscape

I have created a simple SVG file that has a high-resolution JPEG background and some text on top:

- I grabbed [a random high-resolution image form Unsplash](https://unsplash.com/photos/e0DoROpQ8Ew/download?force=true&w=2400)
- I opened it with Inkscape
- I added some text on top
- I saved it as SVG

Now I would like to export it as PDF (keeping the text as-is, not converting it to an image).

I know I can do that with:

```
inkscape --export-type=pdf test.svg
```

The output file, however, is too large. So there is a DPI parameter that should, as I understand, set the resolution of the exported raster images.

However, no matters what value I use, it seems it has no effect on the exported file, which seems to have always the same size and the same background image resolution:

```
inkscape --export-type=pdf --export-dpi=96 test.svg
```

How can I export to PDF while reducing the exported resolution of the background (raster) image and keeping the text as-text?

Looking for a command line (automated) way, since I have many SVG files I would like to export. :-D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation (https://inkscape.org/doc/inkscape-man.html#d-DPI---export-dpi-DPI), the dpi value is not used for embedded images, but only for rasterization of filters. You can make a feature request if you want any changes: https://inkscape.org/report.

You could make a bitmap copy to reduce the resolution. Settings for bitmap copy resolution can be given in a preferences file that is handed to Inkscape on the command line.

Comment: Thanks! https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inbox/-/issues/3720 ^^ Would you mind elaborating a bit more on the bitmap copy process?

Comment: Select object, and if going via menu: Edit > Make a bitmap copy. I don't know the verb / action name offhand, but you can look it up in the verb list / action list. Find the settings for the Bitmap copy dpi in Edit > Preferences > Imported Images.

Comment: Ahhhh, ok. I was looking for an automated way though (command line), since I would need to perform the operation on many images... Doing that manually is not really an option. :-P

Comment: I explained how to find the way to do it via command line ... The man page is here: https://inkscape.org/doc/inkscape-man.html , and the verb-list and action-list will contain the commands that you need .

Comment: You can also provide a custom preferences file to Inkscape from the command line ...